# How to seperate the datas when jquery get them from mysql?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

ChkNewRspLive.php

```
<?php
    $query3 = "SELECT msgid, id FROM rspnotificationlive WHERE username='{$username1}' ORDER BY id LIMIT 99";
    $result3 = mysql_query($query3,$connection) or die (mysql_error());
    confirm_query($result3); 
    $numrspmsg = mysql_num_rows($result3);
    echo $numrspmsg . "|";
    while($userinfo3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
        $rspmsgid= $userinfo3['msgid'];
        $msgid= $userinfo3['id'];
        echo $rspmsgid . ", ";
    }
?>
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get("ChkNewRspLive.php?username=" + username, function(newrspmsg){
        var mySplitResult = newrspmsg.split("|");
        var rspMsgCount = parseFloat(mySplitResult[0]);
        var rspMsgids =(mySplitResult[1]);
        var Msgids = ??//how to get this result from ChkNewRspLive.php ?
});
</script>
```

As you can see, I used "|" to separate `$rspmsgid` and `$numrspmsg`. I also use "," to separate multiple `$rspmsgid`. How if I want to separate another data `$msgid`? How to do that?

If I use | to separate $rspmsgid and $msgid, there will be many sign of | because they both are in the while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSON encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) your content.

In your php, change your code to something like:

```
  $json = array();
    while($userinfo3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
        $rspmsgid= $userinfo3['msgid'];
        $msgid= $userinfo3['id'];
        $json[] = array($rspmsgid,$msgid);
    }
  echo json_encode($json);
```

and then use [$.getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) in your javascript.

You won't have to define the number of mysql_rows either, as you can just get that in javascript by using `.length` on the json data.

**edit** and [escape your string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) before using it in your SQL!

Comment: From the example of $.getJson on the page u gave, I saw $.each(newitems, function(key, val), it is for 1 column array right? How is the codes for 2 columns array like array($rspmsgid,$msgid);
?

Comment: @zac1987 you could use `val[0]` and `val[1]`

Comment: I see. Finally I figured it out. I declare msgid = []; and rspid = []; then $.each(data, function(key, val) {msgid.push(val[0] + ", "); rspid.push(val[1] + ", "); Thanks a lot for your helping. Marked u as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using the .split() method to seperate the other string. Apply it to the other part and let it split by ", " or just use another | instead of the , and you will have it split into three parts instead of two.

However I suggest you have a look at [JSON](http://json.org/). This should be the better solution if it gets more complicated.

Comment: i cannot do that because it is while loop. The 1st | that i have applied is because rspMsgCount is not in while loop.

Comment: Then split by the ", " that you use to seperate the other two ids. Either way I advice you to take a look at JSON and work with something along Niklas' answer. The data has a much clearer structure that way.

Comment: I can't use "," too because I need to separate many $rspmsgid. Sorry about my confusing question, please ignore the line echo $msgid. ", "; Then u will know that there are many $rspmsgid which are separated by ",". Is there any other simple way to do that without Json?

Comment: Just echo both of them and seperate them by another sign, say ";". Your string would look like 3|1;2, 2;2, 3;2 You can just split by | first and have the 3 at position 0. then you split position 1 by "," and get an array with all the msgid and rspmsgid which you then have to split again by ;. That's a lot of splitting and looping for something you could do very easily with JSON.

Comment: Let's say I have $bothArray[] = array($rspmsgid,$msgid); If I didn't echo the $bothArray, how to use javascript to get and display the array elements? Or I need to echo $bothArray?

Comment: Just output them like you do now and add another sign, then split by that sign. You don't need to create an array. Unless you are trying to work with JSON. Then you do what Niklas said and json_encode it. The result you can turn into an array using the file json2.js at [JSON.org](http://json.org) or using the built-in function of jquery that Niklas talks about.